# Are optimization questions better for SO or CodeReview?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, code-review-se

I asked a question on CodeReview today about improving the preformance of my application. I thought it was best suited their because their help center says:

> If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code
>   from your project in the following areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - **Performance**
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!

However, I also took a look at the SO help center which says:

> ...but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - **a software algorithm, or**
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software    development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

In the case of [my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106379/can-i-optimize-this-string-formatting-of-a-can-message) I feel like I'm on the border. I am looking for someone to review my code and see if it can be enhanced in any way, but I'm not sure there is any way to enhance it. Because there may not be a definite answer, I'm not sure it would be accepted well on StackOverflow.

Did I make the right choice? When is an optimization/preformance question better suited for StackOverflow instead of CodeReview, and vise versa?

I am also assuming, but correct me if I'm wrong, that it is bad practice to post a question on multiple SE sites, so a question shouldn't appear on both?

Comment: There is a little bit of crossover between the two, but generally, if your code works and doesn't have a problem that you're trying to solve, it isn't on topic for stackoverflow but might be on topic for codereview. Poor performance can be considered a "problem".

Comment: @gnat wow. I don't know how that didn't come up in my search.

Comment: @KevinB that's a good way to think about it. My code *works* in the sense that there are no errors and runs fine, it's just not quick enough. That means it's not a 'specific programming problem' and may not be a 'practical, answerable problem'; If the code turns out to be optimized to the best anyone can think of, it might just be that my CPU is not fast enough to read from this device. Do you think I made the right choice here?

Comment: I do think codereview was the better choice in this case. though, i almost never use that site, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: As a CR regular I see no obvious problems with it being posted there. Looks like the right call.

Comment: Was I right in holding off from posting to SO as well? I imagine cross-exchange duplicates are harder to catch and even harder to control, so it's better to consolidate the information in one place.

Comment: Yes, it's poor practice to cross-site post, could result in a negative reaction at one or both of the questions.